# Authorization header from Postman not visible in Laravel

Tags: laravel, postman

I am trying to test my Laravel php application with middleware using Postman. The application is using Tymon JWT Auth and according to the [docs](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication) I should set the Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}
```

So, I've added the Authorization header to Postman like so:

[image]

But the response I get from my app is that token is not provided.

It's strange because:

- If I attach the same token to url in Postman, the token is visible to
  the app (status 200 OK and no error saying token_not_provided).
- If I test the app in PHPUnit instead of Postman and provide the token
  either in header or in url, it is also OK.
- Debugging the raw Postman request in Fiddler shows that it actually
  has the Authorization header, as visible below:

[image]

I also tried deleting the other two headers from Postman but it didn't improve anything. So it seems that all is set up fine, but it's not working, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your server on Apache? if yes,the following checklist will be helpful

- You should configure your `.htaccess` properly inside public folder. Refer  [this](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication)
- You should edit `apache2.conf` file

  `sudo vi +164 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
   And change to

  ```
  <Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  ```

  - Then `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
  - Restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

This will work!